# Assigning "content grouping" in Content Engagement Flow (google analytics)

Tags: google-analytics

I'm pretty confident that last week I managed to navigate myself into a popup screen in Analytics which allowed me to "dynamically" assign "content groups" based on url.

This was different than actual content grouping functionality in Analytics since it was asking URL definition and group name.
However, now it seems impossible to find it again?

Answer (score 0):

You can create content groupings via "extractions" from page urls, page titles etc. Click "new content grouping" and expand the "add extractions" pane:

[image]

Comment: No, this is the actual content grouping which I mentioned and can be found in the admin view. What I was looking for is on the content engagement flow view in Analytics itself. But I think that I found it already - just have post a pic about it

Answer (score 0):

By navigating to Behavior > Content Flow and clicking that gear next to Landing Page one can find that popup screen.

Here you can set "dynamic" content groupings based on URL.

[image: By navigating to Behavior > Content Flow and clicking that gear next to Landing Page]